# No Sharepoint Integrated Mode option in Report Server Database Configuration wizard

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I am trying to set up my report server in Sharepoint Integrated mode (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833726.aspx) but I do not get the option to select the mode in the wizard (see image).  Can anybody help?  I am running Sharepoint 2010 with SQL Server 2012 and I selected the option to install in Sharepoint Integrated mode when installing SQL Server.[image]

Answer (score 6):

The link you gave is for SQL 2008 R2.  It has changed a bit in SQL 2012.  Now, the Reporting Services Config Manager can only be used to create a Native mode database.  The options for creating a SharePoint mode database are either using the SP Central Administration page, or by PowerShell command. (Ref - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157285.aspx)). The link has more detail on how to get the SharePoint option up and running.

Also verified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157300.aspx), where it says that in the Reporting Services Config Manager "The Report Server Mode is always set to Native".